# Cocoa UltraSms Database structure

Tags: mysql, database, cocoa, macos, sms

Here's a quicky:
Can someone tell me the table structure that cocoa ultrasms creates or give me a link to a dump of the database? (2 tables)

Cocoa UltraSms is mac only, but I only have my windows machine with me, and I need to recreate the database structure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

well, just in case someone else would ever need it ... smsin tabel:

```
CREATE TABLE `smsin` (
`id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `service` varchar(20) NOT NULL default '',
  `service_number_type` varchar(16) NOT NULL default 'Unknown',
  `service_number_npi` varchar(16) NOT NULL default 'Unknown',
  `status_report_sent` int(1) unsigned NOT NULL default '0',
  `sender` varchar(20) NOT NULL default '',
  `sender_number_type` varchar(16) NOT NULL default 'Unknown',
  `sender_number_npi` varchar(16) NOT NULL default 'Unknown',
  `timestmp` varchar(14) NOT NULL default '',
  `message` text,
  PRIMARY KEY  (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=25 ;
```